# Primefaces resize to get component width

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am using PrimeFaces 5.1 in my project. In my first page to user design page i.e add button press to use to create one `p:dataGrid` row at the time to  `p:selectOneButton` to choose second column is present label or text box this information based create components in my second page in below code I use create template but my doubt **text or label to user to choose to width** so If any other triangle component resize option is avaiable and that resize its possible to I need to resize and get width information to pass  the server is possible or any other way?

```
<p:dataGird value=#{employee.templateList} columns="1" rowIndexVar="rowIndex">
    <h:panelGrid columns="2">
        <h:panelGroup>
            <p:selectOneButton value="#{selectOneView.option}">
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="TextBox" itemValue="TextBox" />
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Label" itemValue="Label" />
            </p:selectOneButton>
        </h:panelGroup>
        <h:panelGroup>....</h:panelGroup>
    </h:panelGrid>
</p:dataGrid>
```

Comment: Sorry, but I have a hard time understanding your question. I'n not a native English speaker, so hopefully you can explain it a little better for me. <aybe imprpvimg the code to an [mcve] and explicitly referring to parts of your code

Comment: I need in  search in dataGrid any resizable component option because that component drag specific size and press the command button pass current components width and height to server because this page include to another page that time I need to fixed component size based on this information.